# Onclick on ok on Javascript can we update custom field

Tags: javascript, custom-button, alert

I want to update field on click of ok in the javascript popup message. Is there any way that i can do in custom button javascript code

like we have checkbox field and when i click on ok in the message the checkbox need to be checked in the backend

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Adding to the answer below if you want to check whether someone has clicked "OK", you will have to use confirm() instead of alert(), something like below would work 
if(window.confirm("Your statement here")){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to create a custom button and then add a javascript to it.

Below is the sample code.Modify it as per your requirement.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}

var r = confirm('Are you Sure?');
if(r == true){
     if({!Account.Checkbox__c} == false)
     {
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Account");
          c.id = "{!Account.Id}";
          c.Checkbox__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
          if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) )
          {
               window.location.reload();
          }
          else
          {
               alert( result[0].errors.message);
          }
     }
     else
     {
          alert("Already True");
     }
}
```

Comment: I think what OP wants is : 1) user clicks the button 2) pop up opens 3) user clicks ok in the popup 4) record updated.  But your solution works this way: 1) User clicks the button 2) Record updates..See difference?

Comment: Yes @javanoob field need to be updated after i click on the ok on popup message, that  means after alert message popup then when user clicks on ok then field need to be updated

Comment: @josyula ,@Javanoob - I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Samir, I made little change i wrote alert message before the if condition and message is showing up when i click on the custom button, After that when i click on ok the field is updating

[image]

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}

 alert("Successfully Submitted");

 if({!Contact.unsubscribe__c} == false)
 {
      var c = new sforce.SObject("Contact");
      c.id = "{!Contact.Id}";
      c.unsubscribe__c = true;
      result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
      if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) )
      {
           window.location.reload();
      }
        else
      {
           alert( result[0].errors.message);
      }
 }
```

Comment: as per my understanding,User should get an option to click Ok or cancel.Only if the user chooses Ok, updation should occur